# Bash - String manipulation in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, substring

I've learned about string manipulation with bash, and more especially about substring replacement:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

VAR1="aaaa.bbbb.cccc"
VAR2="bbbb*"
echo ${VAR1%${VAR2}}
```

This bash script prints "aaaa.". I tried to include it in my makefile, but I can't make it work..

```sh
SHELL:=/bin/bash

VAR1="aaaa.bbbb.cccc"
VAR2="bbbb*"

all:
    @echo $${VAR1%$${VAR2}}
```

This Makefile only prints a blank line.
I think I've misunderstood something, but can't figure out what. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to put double quotes around VAR1 and VAR2. And you need to use `export` if you want to put VAR1 and VAR2 above `all:`

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash

export VAR1=aaaa.bbbb.cccc
export VAR2=bbbb*

all:
    @echo $${VAR1%$${VAR2}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problems is that `VAR1` and `VAR2` are not shell variables, but Makefile variables.
To complicate matters further, each line in the Makefile recipe is executed in a separate shell process, which means the following naive attempt will fail:

```
all:
    VAR1="aaaa.bbbb.cccc"
    VAR2="bbbb*"
    @echo $${VAR1%$${VAR2}}
```

since `VAR1` is defined in one shell, `VAR2` in another, and the `echo` in a third where neither variable is defined. You could use the following:

```
all:
    @VAR1="aaaa.bbbb.cccc"; \
     VAR2="bbbb*"; \
     echo $${VAR1%$${VAR2}};
```

to have a single `bash` statement (all executed in one shell) split into multiple lines in the Makefile.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and your explanations are clear. I thought about some "scoping" for variables, but couldn't find anything about that. Thank you !

Comment: You don't need the curly braces. The backslashes suffice to ensure the command is executed in a single instance of the shell.

Answer (score 0):

B̶a̶s̶h̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶M̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶s̶y̶n̶t̶a̶x̶.̶ ̶ ̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ You can use built-in make functions like (in this case) `$(substr a,b,c)`

[See this](http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-4-SECT-2)

Comment: I knew about those built-in functions but I tried to include native bash in Makefile. chepner gave me the thing I was looking for. Anyway, thank you very much for spending time to answer me :)